# How to have only one instance of program run scheduled task?

Tags: c#, multithreading, scheduled-tasks

My software runs on multiple machines against a single database.

I would like a task to be performed within the software on a daily basis - eg. at midday.

How can I ensure this task is:

- performed only once per day,
- performed no matter which machine/user happens to be running the software that day, and
- not performed simultaneously with any other instances of the software?

Comment: What if nobody is running the software one day?

Comment: Why don't you keep track of jobs execution in database using your custom columns as locks to avoid reexecution ?

Comment: @Polynomial: that's too bad if that happens. Nothing I can do.

Comment: @CraigJ So your customers will have to raise a support ticket every time they have a training day, or a team-building day, or have a lot of staff off on xmas holidays? Doesn't sound ideal.

Comment: No, the task is not critical, just a nice-to-have. I guess someone could leave the program running if they are going to be away for a day.  In any case, the task would remain in the queue and just be done next day the program runs.

Comment: @CraigJ For a nice-to-have, it sounds like a lot of effort and complexity. What's the barrier to running a cronjob or scheduled task on the database box?

Comment: The software is run in a large enterprise environment which would not let me run any processes on their servers.

Comment: `My software` what software? Every program is different and every platform has different "tasks" it can perform. `this task` what task? Why does it have to be performed by an instance of the program instead of by another program, or by the database?

Comment: @Furqan: what do you mean by 'custom columns'?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with doing it in the client is that your users might not run the software at all one day, or they might suffer a hardware failure (e.g. power loss) during the operation, causing a perpetual locked row. You cannot guarantee task integrity, and you can't even guarantee that the task will run.

If you need to ensure that it runs regardless of the user actually using your software every day, this lends itself to a scheduled task (which are available for [Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) and [Linux / UNIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)) on the database server.

Create an executable that performs the task, then create a scheduled task to run it daily. This way you've got one instance that will *always* run, as long as the database machine is up, and you don't have to worry about tracking job execution across clients.

---

Ok, so you're now saying you can't run scheduled tasks on the database box due to corporate rules. Here's the scheme I'd use:

1. Create a table for job scheduling. Give each job a date / time to run, a time the job started (null if not started), a progress field, as well as a name and other information you need for the task.
2. Have each client poll every 5 minutes or so, to run a query to find jobs that have dates in the past. Select the first job whose row is not locked.
3. Lock the row and update the "time job started" field to the current time.
4. Perform the task, updating the progress field as parts of the job complete.
5. Delete the row on success, else flag the row as "failed".

The important part is the "time job started" field, which allows clients to check if a job was started a long time ago (e.g. 3 hours) but never completed, so it can be retried or a user alerted, depending on the progress value.

Comment: The database I am using has no such facility. It must be done in the software.

Comment: The task scheduler is not provided by the database. It's part of the operating system. On Windows, you can use the task scheduler. On Linux, you can use cron.

Comment: Agreed, this must be controlled by the OS not the application itself.  In Windows scheduled tasks (not sure about cron jobs) there is specific functionality to allow only a single process for the task.

Comment: @Terric Cron jobs just run a command, so a cron job would look like "run this command at 3pm every day". As long as the command doesn't take >24 hours to complete (!!), you'll only ever have one instance performing the task.

Comment: Can't be in a task scheduler. Some enterprise environments will not allow such tasks to be created on their systems.

Comment: @CraigJ It sounds like what you're saying then, is this "enterprise environment" won't allow you to do things the right way - but are happy to invest the time / resources into finding a botch way around the right way - this doesn't make sense.  We're not sure of your exact requirements, but I'd certainly take a look at why they won't allow this to be a scheduled process.

Comment: Far easier for me to just have it in the client software. If I can handle the concurrency issues then I think it would be more elegant solution because I don't have to add another structure to the architecture.

Comment: @CraigJ as another thought, if they are really insistent that you can't create this scheduled process on their servers - can you not create it on a client as a task?  I've little experience in Linux, but in Windows you can set the task to run whether the user is logged on or not - as long as that client's machine is powered on it will run.

Comment: It'll be a general security thing.  Security means stopping hackers doing stuff, the side-effect being that it stops developers doing stuff as well.  It would be really nice to just turn up at an airport and walk out to the plane :)

Comment: @Terric: they wouldn't let me create a task on the client machines either.

Comment: @CraigJ OK, wow... so they won't allow you to create a scheduled task on a client's machine to run this program at an interval... but they'll let you run the program directly on the same client's machine??? Weird - OK, so in that case can you not just make a console app, put the logic in a thread and set that thread to run in an infinite loop with a low priority.  Get it to create a text file daily with a date in, if that text file is present and it has today's date then just don't perform the logic - otherwise delete the file and recreate with today's date?

Comment: @Terric: why bother with the separate console app, why not just include all the logic in the one app?

Comment: @CraigJ yeah I suppose I didn't word that right. I didn't necessarily mean a **separate** app, I've a habit of creating things like this as a console app so just assumed that's what your current app was. There's no reason why you can't incorporate this logic in your app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a table with a single row in a database. Use transactions to lock the row containing the last update date.

Every X minutes:

- If the record is locked, it means someone is performing the job. Do nothing.
- If the record is outdated and unlocked, lock it and do the job. If it fails, unlock the record. If it succeeds, update the record with the current date.
- If the record contains the current date, do nothing.

---

**Example using SQL Server**

If you run this in a transaction, it will lock the row from other clients

```
UPDATE Test WITH (ROWLOCK)
SET UpdateDate = yourDate
WHERE PrimaryKey = yourkey
```

Comment: And if nobody runs the software one day? Or if the machine suffers a power failure after locking the row?

Comment: What do you mean by 'lock the row'?  Transactions will not lock the row.

Comment: @Polynomial when running in a transaction, a power failure shouldn't be a problem. If nobody runs the software, then, hmm nobody runs the software... ;-)

Comment: @JohannBlais: as an alternative, because I don't think my database server will accept that SQL, could I just have a field called "LOCKED" and set it to true?

Comment: Normally any half decent database software should be able to lock a row/table from being read while writes are pending in a transaction. Even without a specific syntax like SQL Server has.